# Applicaiton object is coming null in ViewModel in wpf, trying to access Application variables

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, app.xaml

I am working on WPF application which contains two usercontrols, i am trying to set a Application variable and assigning some value at viewModel loads. This viewmodel is bind with my UserControl.

Question is how can i get and set the APplication variables in wpf. Whatever i have tried i am writing below.

```
App.xaml.cs

public string globalText = "";
public bool isNewUser;
public App()
{
    isNewUser = true;
}


MyViewModel.cs

App currentApp = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<App>().FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
App currentApp = (App)System.Windows.Application.Current;
```

Above both ways i have tried but in both ways i am getting CurrentApp null.

i tried to add some value as below.

```
if(currentApp.IsNewUser)
{
   CurrentApp1.globalText = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<App>()` makes no sense, since it tries to find an App in the Windows collection of the current Application. That said, if both isNewUser and globalText  are in the App class, why does the view model need to bother with it. Leave that logic in the App class.

Comment: I checked it and it does work. ((App)Application.Current)

Comment: If I am writing App thisApp = ((App)Application.Current); it is donating to my other project which is added in same solution. i have to projects in one solution. FirstProject is consumed by SecondProject. so If i write above syntax in FirstProject's my class than it will auto denote to SecondProject. It is strange for me but it is happening.

Comment: Why down votes? strange!

Comment: I am getting exception System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'SecondProject.App' to type 'FirstProject.App'.' While syntax App thisApp = ((App)Application.Current);  is written in FirstProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting exception `System.InvalidCastException`: 'Unable to cast object of type 'SecondProject.App' to type 'FirstProject.App'.' While syntax `App thisApp = ((App)Application.Current);` is written in FirstProject.

If you have two `App` classes in scope you could reference the correct one using its fully qualifed type name:

```
App thisApp = (FirstProject.App)Application.Current;
```

Comment: Need a vote up to my question, my question was correct. Please vote up, It worked for me, Thank you so much.

Comment: Done it sir! :)